# RecyclerView wrap 2 items instead of all content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The problem is that `RecyclerView` with `height = "wrap_content"` doesn't wrap all content, but it measure height to only 2 adapter items.

Best describe this screenshots : https://i.stack.imgur.com/huPHQ.jpg

It worked fine for me since 23.2.0 update, but now for some unknown reason stopped work.
I have tried with `compile com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0 , 23.2.1, 24.0.0` and it doesn't work on any of this versions.

Code:

Gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 93
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    ...
}
```

Java:

```
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerFlavors = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerViewFlavors.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerFlavors);
recyclerViewFlavors.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), null));
//recyclerViewFlavors.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
FlavosAdapter flavorsAdapter = new FlavosAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Flavor>());
recyclerViewFlavors.setAdapter(flavorsAdapter);
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_fragment_liquids_views_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/liquid_name"
        style="@style/TextViewStyleTitle"
        android:text="@string/liquid_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/liquid_description"
        style="@style/TextViewStyleTitle"
        android:text="@string/liquid_description"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_target_big" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextViewTitleBig"
            android:text="@string/liquid_target" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextViewStyleTitleTwo"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_target_liquid"
            android:text="@string/liquid_amount" />

        <TextView

            style="@style/TextViewStyleTitleTwo"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_nicotine_strength"
            android:text="@string/liquid_str" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_target_ml"
            style="@style/TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_target_ml"
                style="@style/EditTextInteger"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="[ml]"
                android:text="10" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_target_strength"
            style="@style/TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_target_strength"
                style="@style/EditTextFloatingPoint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="[mg/ml]"
                android:text="6" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        style="@style/TextViewStyleTitle"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_vpg"
        android:text="@string/liquid_subtitle_target_ratio"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <app.minimize.com.seek_bar_compat.SeekBarCompat
        android:id="@+id/slider_target"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_target_vg"
            style="@style/TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_target_vg"
                style="@style/EditTextInteger"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="VG [%]" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_target_pg"
            style="@style/TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_target_pg"
                style="@style/EditTextInteger"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="PG [%]" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_flavors_big" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextViewTitleBig"
            android:text="@string/liquid_flavors_title" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_flavors"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/image_button_add_flavor"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/image_button_add_flavor_from_database"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_flavor_from_database" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_flavor_name"
                    style="@style/TextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_flavor_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_flavor_name"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_flavor_percentage"
                    style="@style/TextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_flavor_percentage"
                        style="@style/EditTextFloatingPoint"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:hint="[%]" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_flavor_vpg"
                    style="@style/TextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_flavor_vpg"
                        style="@style/EditTextFloatingPoint"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="PG[%]"
                        android:text="100" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_flavor_price"
                    style="@style/TextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_flavor_price"
                        style="@style/EditTextFloatingPoint"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_price_for_10ml" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/textColorSecondary" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/result_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_recipe_big" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_recipe"
            style="@style/TextViewTitleBig"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/liquid_recipe_title" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/text_view_show_results"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/showresults"
            android:text="@string/liquid_button_show_results"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorWhite" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/image_button_toggle_chart"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_chart"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_button_show_save"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_save_recipe" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_button_show_share"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share_liquid" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_button_show_settings"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView_blender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_blender" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/results_titles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result_row_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:text="@string/results_name"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result_row_percentage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="[%]"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result_row_ml"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="[ml]"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:id="@+id/result_row_drips"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/result_drips_title"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                autofit:minTextSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result_row_weight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="[g]"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result_row_cost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="[$]"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.PieChartView
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_consume_batch"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ask_if_consume_flavors_from_batch" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:id="@+id/button_cancel_consume"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/consume"
                android:id="@+id/button_apply_consume"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Item View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_row_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result_row_percentage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="50.0"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/result_row_ml"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="100.0"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/result_row_drips"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/result_row_weight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/result_row_cost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="10.5"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: because you have many things above and below `RecycleView`. Post your full layout..!!

Comment: It's not the best idea since this layout has 673 lines of code, do you thing it may cause the problem ?

Comment: Then i can only say.. the problem is in your 673 line code..!! The number on lines cannot be the problem it is the properties you have set in your Views.

Comment: Ok, I have updated full layout

Comment: see if you suppose to wrap all items of your recylceview your other items my Go out of vision..!! What is recycleView have 10 items

Comment: I don't understand, could you please write it again ?